# Shared war between virtual hosts

Tags: java, war, tomcat8

I am running Tomcat 8.5 on a windows server. I have setup a virtual host in the server.xml so that I now have domain1.com which goes to the defaultapp and domain2.com which goes to the virtual host. This works fine.

The 2 domains have different web apps but share some of the Java war modules. Is it possible to share these so that they are loaded only once and not twice for each host?

I might not have been clear: what I have is 2 web applications hosted on the different virtual hosts but they call restful APIs.

Some of those APIs are common and rather than having a war module instanced in both virtual hosts is it possible to have a common instance used by both virtual hosts?

The only thing I could think of is having all the API war modules in one virtual host and have the other virtual host web app call API there.

Does that make sense? Is there an alternative?

EDIT: To be clearer a virtual host refers to Virtual Hosting and Tomcat on this page https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html

Comment: *"I might not have been clear: what I have is 2 web applications hosted on the different virtual hosts ... "* - If you want to be clear, you need to explain what >you< mean by "virtual host".  It has multiple (plausible) meanings.

Comment: Ah I mean virtual host as in Virtual Hosting and Tomcat on this Tomcat page https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html

Comment: Yes: it's possible

Comment: @MauricePerry Can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: @RobertKovacs well as you said: you can have your API on either virtual host (or even a third one), and both your webapps can send requests to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I have adopted is to have the 2 web apps to call a common url for all api calls.

So I will have virtualhost domain1 hosting its own angular web components and the backend server modules.

Virtualhost domain2 will hostonly its angular web components and make calls to the backend server modules using the domain1 url.

Thanks go to @mauriceperry for confirming  this idea.

Answer (score -1):

In tomcat you don't have .ear like in JEE server that can do complexe sharing.
It's more simple :

```
      Bootstrap
          |
       System
          |
       Common
       /     \
  Webapp1   Webapp2 ...
```

So you can put .jar files in "Common" to copy jar files in $CATALINA_BASE/lib and you can remove them from .war files.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. However I might not have been clear. what I have is 2 web applications hosted on the different virtual hosts but they call restful APIs. Some of those APIs are common and rather than having a war module instanced in both virtual hosts is it possible to have a common instance used by both virtual hosts?
The only thing I could think of is having all the API war modules in one virtual host and have the other virtual host web app call API there. 
Does that make sense?

Comment: OK maybe use a symlink

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the symlink would work in this case? I do not think that would work as I only want 1 instance of the war running I do not believe a symlink would stop that.